# C# Vector.Add with PointF

Tags: c#, vector, drawing

I am programming a little program for interpreting and drawing G-Code (used for CNC - machines)

For linking two lines with a radius i wrote a little program and have to use the function Vector.Add.

```
No code, had probelems with formatting :)
p1,p2,p3 are the three points 
p1->p2 = vector ab 
p2->p3 = vector bc 
eab = Unit vector ab 
ebc = Unit vector bc 
eres = resulting vector
```

My problem is: For the operation `Vector.Add()` I need a `Vector` and a `Point`(`PointF` is not allowed) but I have to use `PointF` due to the accuracy. 
What shall I do?

```
eab = ab / ab.Length;
ebc = bc / bc.Length;
eres = Vector.Add(eab, ebc);
PointF test= new PointF();
test= Vector.Add(5 * eres, test );
```

I use `System.Windows.Drawing` for drawing and `System.Windows.Base` for the vectors.

Comment: what drawing framework do you use? GDI ?

Comment: First of all, while both have a x and y (maybe a z) value, a Vector and a Point can't be added. You can't add points, you can add Vectors. Also you say "due to accuracy" i'm pretty sure that Vector and PointF both use floats for their values, so were do you want to get more accuracy? Besides, what about Vector.Add( myVec, new Vector(myPt.X, myPt.Y));

Comment: using system.base with namespace system.windows
ok i always thought Point are only Integer values 
thanks ill try that

Comment: @user1897553: considering that you're writing a program that has to draw a CNC drawing, so the drawing that follows machine that can operate on **microns** precision level, GDI+ is a bad choice. Choose some  advance draing library for this, like OpenGL and draw stuff in 2D/3D. Just an example of library (can peak whatever you like): [OpenTk](http://www.opentk.com/)

Comment: Are you confusing the struct `System.Windows.Point` from the WindowsBase.dll with the `System.Drawing.Point` struct of System.Drawing.dll? What's the namespace of `Vector`?

Comment: 1st comment: Point is just for integer values isnt it? And i need a little exacter with PointF, is that wrong?!
 2nd comment: I am not really used to work with different libraries but i will try thanks :)

@Jeppe u are right didnt realize that. WHat could i do?
the namespace of Vector is System.Windows.

Comment: @user1897553 See my updated answer below. If you feel my answer solves your problem, set the check mark `✔` to the left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the System.Drawing.dll, namespace `System.Drawing`, there are:

```
public struct Point { ... }
public struct PointF { ... }
```

whose coordinates are `int` (`System.Int32`) and `float` (`System.Single`), respectively.

In the WindowsBase.dll, namespace `System.Windows`, there is *another*:

```
public struct Point { ... }
```

whose coordinates are `double` (`System.Double`).

If you need both, you can

- Have both the directives `using System.Drawing;` and `using System.Windows;` at the same level in your file, and then inside the code give the full name (like e.g. `System.Winodws.Point` instead of just `Point`) whenever there's disambiguity (that is whenever the compiler requires that). Or:
- Have only one of the using directives (the one you use the most), and then give the full name in cases where you use types (like structs) from the other namespace. Or:
- Create one or more [`using` *alias* directives (see link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).